# How would you credit people who gave writing suggestions but did not actually participate in writing?

Tags: production, credits

I am participating in an amateur short movie project, and we had several online meetings to discuss all the various aspects of it, including the plot. The script was basically written by me and the director, who I will credit for writing. But during those meetings, a lot of people gave very good insights that helped correcting, guiding and shaping the plot. Some even had ideas that were written alsmost word for word as is in the final script.

I don't want not to credit them at all. How would you call that ? I was thinking "Writing Support" or "Story Development".

Comment: The writers guild will have rules about this and it is there this should be directed, not the opinions of random people on the internet.

Comment: https://www.wga.org/uploadedfiles/credits/manuals/screenscredits_manual18.pdf - The WGA says that you can't credit a third writer and you can't make up bespoke writing credit titles. You can thank them, but that's it. - "***“Written by” credit generally will not be shared by more than two writers.***" + "***Any form of credit not expressly described in this Manual shall be used only upon receipt of a waiver from the Guild***"

Comment: @Paulie_D - I strongly suspect that nobody involved in this production will be a member of the WGA or similar. This is an amateur project, which means that they can do whatever they like...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, as discussed in the [meta] post, "[Do we want practical questions about movie production?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1234/1006)", questions about making new movies or TV shows are off-topic here.

Comment: @galacticninja The most upvoted answer there mentions how "it depends", and I believe this question's answer gives us insight into general production practices. Nevertheless, maybe it's more appropriate if the OP [edit]s the question to make it less personal and specific.

Comment: @Joachim The top-voted answer says: "*no: it is not fair game to ask for advice about making a new work*." The two other answers, both with positive scores, echo this sentiment.

Comment: While questions about film-making can sometimes verge into advice, this question really is the prime example of personal film-making advice that this site really doesn't do. If this ought to be reopened, there needs to be put some effort into rephrasing it into less of a personal writing advice. Otherwise, [writing.se] (or any place else) would likely be a better place for this.

Comment: Relevant [meta] post about this question: [Is it on-topic to ask for advice on filmmaking?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4959/1006)

Comment: I don't know. But I bet Orson Welles would storm out if you asked it from him.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A professional project should use the WGA guidelines, and an amateur one could read those guidelines for a better insight.

Many professional writers will thank people (family, friends) for their help, in a very different and less formal way than they would do following WGA guidelines. You often read/see "*thanks to Alice for her help, tips and support bla-bla-bla*".

You probably could do something like that. You don't credit them as co-writers but as "*people who helped*" (whatever that help was).

"*Thanks to Alice, Bob, Charlotte and Dwayne for their tips and help. This story wouldn't have been the same without some of your ideas, and your remarks were inspiring.*" You can also use the idea of Scott Myers (see below - emphasis mine)

It's a very different story with pros, where credits are codified. From and for the pros:

> A participating writer is defined as a writer who has participated in the writing of the screenplay, or a writer who has been employed by the Company on the story and/or screenplay, or a "professional writer" who has sold or licensed literary material subject to the MBA.
>
> When more than one writer has participated in the writing of a motion picture, then all participating writers have the right to agree unanimously among themselves as to which of them shall receive writing credits on the screen and in what form, provided that the form agreed upon is in accordance with the terms of Theatrical Schedule A of the MBA, and provided the agreement is reached in advance of arbitration.
>
> [WGA - screen credits](https://www.wga.org/contracts/credits/manuals/screen-credits-manual)

Screenwriter Scott Myers, a WGA member, has questioned why more than three writers cannot be credited:

> After the official Written By or Screenplay By credits are determined, **why not in end credits add "Additional Writing Services," then list all the other writers?** Everybody and their mother who works on a movie gets a credit. Why not all the writers? [How writing credits work](https://scottdistillery.medium.com/reader-question-could-you-explain-how-writing-credits-work-77c3dbab2232)

Comment: Even though I had classes in legalese in university, sentences like "A participating writer is defined as a writer who has participated in the writing […]" make me chuckle. Especially since the second and third sub-clause add more people to the definition of "participating writer" who are *not* "writers who have participated in the writing". Or, in other words, a "participating writer" need not necessarily be a "writer who has participated in the writing", which implies that you can be a participating writer without having participated in writing.

Comment: @JörgWMittag : read the entire stuff and you'll be even more amazed ;) like, sometimes,  even if all agree, one has to file a complain in order that the case be settled by the WGA with no further complain possible. Talk about lawyer gobbledygook...